# Error "is not a JSONObject"

Tags: android, mysql, sql, json

I have JSON string:

```
{ "products" : [ { "created_at" : "2014-04-09 23:10:15",
        "name" : "tessss",
        "pid" : "1",
        "price" : "10.00",
        "updated_at" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      },
      { "created_at" : "2014-04-10 21:14:51",
        "name" : "avgs",
        "pid" : "2",
        "price" : "20.00",
        "updated_at" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      }
    ],
  "success" : 1
}
```

My code is (line is JSON string):

```
JSONObject nodeRoot  = new JSONObject(line); 

// Creating a sub-JSONObject from another JSONObject
JSONObject nodeStats = nodeRoot.getJSONObject("products");

// Getting the value of a attribute in a JSONObject
String sSDR = nodeStats.getString("name");
System.out.println(sSDR);
```

And when I run I get error `JSONObject["products"] is not a JSONObject.`

Comment: products is an array not object please read some tutorial first about json at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{` represents JSONObject and `[` represents the JSONArray

In your json  products represents `JSONArray` not `Object`

DO like this to get the name string.

```
JSONObject nodeRoot  = new JSONObject(line); 
JSONArray nodeStats = nodeRoot.getJSONArray("products");
for(int i=0; i < nodeStats.length();i++){
String sSDR = nodeStats.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
 }
```